# How to navigate through code in Visual Studio Code in a .Net project like in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

How can you navigate through code in Visual Studio Code in a .Net project like in Visual Studio? What I mean is in Visual Studio I can see the active link to the source i.e. some interface, class, etc. In Visual Studio Code I only see the patch.  I know I can go to it with <kbd>F12</kbd>, but if there is a way to do it with mouse clicking?

Tried to serch some extensions but never found one.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the active link to the source i.e. some interface, class, etc. In Visual Studio Code I only see the patch".  Maybe some screenshots might help of what you mean?

Comment: You can raise feature requests at https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode or better help implement them.